How to use docker with old engine version in Windows
I currently have Docker Destop 4.28, with engine v25.0.3.
I need to have engine v20-24 for a project, but I haven't found any resources on how to do this with Windows.

Why do you need a specific engine version? What is the underlying problem you are trying to solve? This fella like an https://xyproblem.info/

@BMitch i'm trying to build openmetadata. They have a prerequisites make target that says only Docker 20-24 are supported.

The instructions say 20.10 or greater for Linux, and Windows just lists the version for Ubuntu. Where are you seeing the v20-24? https://github.com/open-metadata/OpenMetadata/blob/main/openmetadata-docs/content/v1.3.x/quick-start/local-docker-deployment.md. Do you have an error message to include in the question?

When I run make prerequisites it says 'Docker 25 is not supported, only 20 21 22 23 24 are supported. I didn't wanna move forward to avoid any inconveniences, no error yet.

I would try changing the script to see if it works. And if so, file a bug report or PR with the project. https://github.com/open-metadata/OpenMetadata/blob/14698aff62f3f0e4a3e677b7ff2dfbe60ab7f6f2/scripts/check_prerequisites.sh#L33
